# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') while using Interceptor

Tags: node.js, angular

I have the following Angular and Node JS as follows

**Interceptor**

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "../Services/auth.service";

@Injectable()

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService : AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    //console.log(this.authService.getAuthToken())
    const authToken = this.authService.getAuthToken();
    const authRequest = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", authToken)
    });
    console.log("authRequest");

    return next.handle(authRequest);
  }


}
```

**service**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { api_url } from '../Models/global-url.model';
import { LoginModel } from '../Models/login_details.model';
import { ResponseFromServer } from '../Models/response.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private token : string;
  //Password is asish for all users
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  checkUserLogin(loginDetails: LoginModel) {
    console.log(loginDetails);
      this.http.post<{response: any}>(api_url+"login/loginUser", loginDetails).subscribe((result: ResponseFromServer) => {
      console.log(result.token);
      this.token = result.token;
      console.log(this.token);

    });
  }
  getAuthToken() {
    return this.token;
  }
}
```

**User Defined Middleware in Node JS :-**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const s_token = require('../tokens/auth-token');

//const authFunction = (req, res, next) => {

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req);
    var message = '';
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization;
        console.log(token);
        jwt.verify(token, s_token);
        next();

    } catch (err) {
        message = "Auth Failed";
        console.log(err); //JsonWebTokenError: Error jwt must be provided => user is not logged in
        res.status(401).json(message);

        // res.json(message); //Check the error message that occurs in browser console, while using this without status
    }
}
```

**login.js in Node Router :-**

```
router.post('/loginUser', async (req, res, next) => {
    const loginDetails  = req.body;
    console.log(loginDetails);
    var { userId, stored_password,userEmailId,token,status_code } = '';
    var message = '';
    var response = '';
    //console.log(loginDetails);
    query = `SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE (tum_email = $1 OR tum_mobile = $1)`;
    params = [loginDetails.username];

    // await db.query(query, params, (err, result) => {
    //     if(err) {
    //         console.log(err);
    //         response = 'f0';
    //         message = "Internal Server Error. Please reload the page and try again.";
    //     } else if(result.rows.length) {
    //         //console.log(result.rows.length);
    //         userId = result.rows[0].tum_email;
    //         password = result.rows[0].tum_password;
    //         response = 's1';
    //         message = ""; 
    //     } else {
    //         response = 'f1';
    //         message = "User with the given user id does not exist. Please register here";
    //     }
        
    // });
    try {
            const result = await db.query(query, params);
            if(result.rowCount == 0 ) {
                response = 'f1';
                message = "User with the given user id does not exist. Please register here";
            } else {
                userId = result.rows[0].tum_id;
                userEmailId = result.rows[0].tum_id;
                stored_password = result.rows[0].tum_password;
                
                try {
                    if ((await argon2.verify(stored_password, loginDetails.password))) {
                       
                        //password matches
                        response = 'success';
                        const session_data = {
                            userId: userId,
                            email: userEmailId
                        }
                        token = jwt.sign(session_data, s_token, {expiresIn:'1hr'});
                        
                        //console.log(token);

                    } else { 
                        response = 'f2';
                        message = "Entered password is wrong. Please enter the correct password, or reset it";
                    }

                    


                  } catch (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    response = 'f0';
                    message = "Internal Server Error. Please reload the page and try again, or contact an Administrator";
                  } 
            }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        response = 'f0';
        message = "Internal Server Error. Please reload the page and try again, or contact an Administrator";
    }
    

    const json_object = {
        token: token,
        response: response,
        message:message
    }
    if(token != '') {
        status_code = 200;
    } else {
        status_code = 401;
    }
    
    res.status(status_code).json(json_object);
    //console.log("response ="+response+" & message = "+ message);
});
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthData } from 'src/app/Models/auth_data.model';
import { LoginModel } from 'src/app/Models/login_details.model';
import { ResponseFromServer } from 'src/app/Models/response.model';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/Services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  isSubmitted = false;
  isValid = true;
  isLoading = false;
  response_from_server = new ResponseFromServer();

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {


  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.response_from_server.response = 's1';
  }

  loginUser(loginData: NgForm) {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if(loginData.invalid) {
      this.isValid = false;
      //console.log("Validation Errors");
      return;
    }
    const loginDetails : LoginModel = {
      username : loginData.value.username,
      password: loginData.value.password
    }

    this.authService.checkUserLogin(loginDetails);


  }

}
```

Whenever I try to login , the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` is thrown.

The data is not even sent to the server side. It is stuck before `return next.handle(authRequest);`.

I tried `console.log()` almost everywhere to see where I am getting the mistake, and to which part, the data movement is getting done. Looks like the email and password are not even going through, to the Node JS server. Using `console.log(result.token)` in `login.service.ts` does not have any value.

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely happening because your trying to add the Authorization header before the user is logged-in.

In that situation `authToken` is `undefined` and you are assigning it to the header anyways.

You could solve it just adding a guard in your intercept method to first check if you have an authToken before attaching it to the request.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  const authToken = this.authService.getAuthToken();

  if(!authToken) { // <--- not logged-in skip adding the header
    return next.handle(req);
  }

  const authRequest = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", authToken)
  });

  return next.handle(authRequest);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: darn it. I knew that auth was getting implemented before logging in, but I didnt know how to fix it. Thanks a ton, for going through all the codes of mine. Seriously!!